# Import "pandas" could not be resolved from source Pylance

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, importerror

i am very new to Python and i got the problem that the import from module "pandas" and "requests" can not be resolved, while another import from OS can be solved in the same file.

I have tried the following and the problem is not yet solved:

1. reinstall python and vscode
2. reconfigure the PATH variables (since VSCode is complaining about '''' in the path, so i thought this maybe relevant. Now it stops complaining but the issue import can still not be resolved)
3. use "pip install pandas"(The terminal shows me that "requirement already satisfied" and i can find a not empty folder called pandas in explorer according to the address provided).
4. synchronize the version of python 3(so now he one shown on the right bottom of vscode window(3.10.10 64 bit) is the same as the one from terminal when i call python(3.10.10))
5. try to create a venv and select interpreter there(not 100% sure i did that right, but now my vscode looks like this image [vscode view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgMDF.png)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Update: i turned to IntelliJ .It detected the missing packages and installed for me. While everything is fine with IntelliJ, vsCode still won't work.

I still can not figure out why though.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the VSCode terminal, is the right virtualenv auto selected?
If it is, check dependencies are all installed in that by doing `pip freeze`.

Also check the selected python path by running `which python` or `which python3`

The above command would give you the full path of virtualenv selected. Make sure that is the environment you have installed all the dependencies.

Can you also post the steps taken to select the interpreter in VSCode?

NOTE: Better to import the pandas like `import pandas as pd`
using `import *` is not a good practice.

Comment: So i have done the following to select interpreter in my 4-th try
1. click the version at the right bottom part
2.select from the dropdown menu which shows available interpreters(i have two 3,10,10 since i have also download from microsoft store)

After trying to install the venv i now have two extra interpreters of version 3.11.2( which is actually are not to be found in the corresponding path in the explorer)